# “minimal BASH like line editing is supported”

Tags: kali-linux, grub2, dual-boot, elementary-os

I'm getting this error “minimal BASH like line editing is supported” instead of grub menu when I try to install GNU-Linux(Kali OS) as a dual boot. Can anyone help me in a easy understandable way?

*I had earlier elementary OS(GNU-Linux) as a dual boot.
My main OS is Windows 10.

Thanks

Comment: why do you believe that this is an error message ? `minimal BASH like line editing is supported`

Comment: Use your favorite search engine to search for Bash/readline keybindings. Why do you think this is an error?

Comment: Kali Linux is designer for security experts, it is not meant to be installed. It is best use as a live OS. It is not intended for the same audience that Elementary is aimed at. You should probably chose a different Gnu/Linux. (grab a pin, and choose one, you will probably get a better choice. However I recommend Debian. It is good, reliable, avoids non-free, and is easy to use.)

Comment: @jsotola #Arkadiusz Drabczyk Cause it's not letting me install normally!. #ctrl-alt-delor I'm learning ethical hacking.

Comment: @SunilKumarDas You can use Kali as a persistent live boot and do all the things necessary for ethical hacking. And actually you can get most tools on Windows too.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor #kemotep grub menu not showing.

Comment: Most or all of the tools are available on Debian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this problem with the newer versions of Kali Linux.

Turns out the problem is with the program you must have used to burn the ISO to the USB as I was using anyburn and balena etcher.

I solved this problem by using a program called Rufus to burn the ISO to the USB. But first time I still had problems with installation of Kali because the image burning was not clear. So I burnt the image to the USB again using Rufus but I got like 4 notifications warning about virus threat so I allowed them all and after the burning of the USB was complete I went to allowed threats and blocked the threat's but after the Kali Linux USB was good to go.

now I have no Idea why rufus gets false positives from the antivirus software guess it has something to do with the kali linux unpacking and burning so I guess it has nothing to do with the rufus program itself + u can download rufus from https://rufus.ie/en/

Comment: Hello. Thank you for taking your time to share a solution which worked for you. Could you please [edit] your post to tell which program that you used for burning caused the booting problem? It would be also great if you reference why Rufus possibly gets false positives from an antivirus and where to download it reliably from. It is generally not safe to ignore security warnings.

Comment: Please also remember that, if the problem is caused by the software which is not in Linux or Unix, it is usually off-topic here and better be asked on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).